# Complete normality of product topological space $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{R}}$

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to find a counterexample that is a compact $T_5$ but not $T_6$.
Consequently, I want to prove the following topological space is completely normal.

Let $(\{0,1\},\tau )$ be the discrete topological space and $(Y=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{R}},\mathscr{T}_p)$ be the product topological space.
$(Y , \mathscr{T}_p)$ is a compact and hausdorff space. Thus, $(Y , \mathscr{T}_p)$ is $T_4$.

From this question[Is a separable compact Hausdorff space perfectly normal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1724577/is-a-separable-compact-hausdorff-space-perfectly-normal), we can get that$(Y , \mathscr{T}_p)$ is not perfectly normal.

A topological space $(X, \mathscr{T})$ is completely normal $\iff$ every open set $U$ is normal in its relative topology of  $(X, \mathscr{T})$.  For $(Y , \mathscr{T}_p)$, it has a natural base $\mathscr{B}$ such that every open set in the base is normal.  A open set $U\in \mathscr{T}_p$ is a set of union of some elements in the base. Thus, I want to prove that for every closed set $A$ in $U$ and every open neighborhood $V$ of $A$ in $U$, there exists some open neighborhood of $A$ in $U$ such that $cl_{\mathscr{T}_{p,U}}(V')\subset U$.

What can I do next?

Comment: You can look for a counterexample, as it's not $T_5$,

Comment: Are $T_5, T_6$ standard terms?

Comment: @GEdgar I know them as such. They're used in Engelking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's well-known that the non-normal Tychonoff plank embeds as a subspace $T \subseteq X:=\{0,1\}^{\Bbb R}$ as its zero-dimensional Hausdorff of weight $\le \mathfrak{c}$ (embedding theorem). So $T$ is a non-normal subspace of $X$ so $X$ is not $T_5$ (which is equivalent to every subspace being $T_4$)... We could also use the Sorgenfrey plane if you prefer..

A compact $T_5$ but not $T_6$ space can be gotten by the double arrow space.